# Xui js input value

Tags: xui

i'm using xui.js (v 2.3.2) and try to return the value of an input text field.

```
x$('#field-email').value -> return undefined
x$('#field-email').attr('value') -> return ['name@domain.com'] including bracket and quote.
```

What I don't understand is why the first sample return undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`x$('#field-email')` don't returns DOMElement, it returns the xui object with elements selected by css selector. You can access input value this way: `x$('#field-email')[0].value`.

Answer (score 0):

Paul´s right. if you get an Element by x$('#field-email')[0] ,you can use simple JS functions like x$('#field-email')[0].tagName. THis would return the Tag name..